# Add Name/Total column in R

Tags: r

I'm a totally newbie. I Would like to add a SUM column ("all"), so for exemple 1st row should be 5, 2nd is 3, etc. Also, to add a name ("ID") to the first column. Please keep it as simple as possible, preferably aggregate code or something like that.

Code:

```
n.actors <- table(IMDB_players$id,IMDB_players$role)
n.actors.df <- as.data.frame(n.actors)
head(n.actors)
```

Thanks,
Gilbert

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please don't upload code or data as images. [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) explains why it's incredibly unhelpful for many reasons.  A far better alternative is to edit your post to include the output from `dput()` or `dput(head())`.

Comment: Also including some data we can use is helpful. And as for your question, see `rowSums()` and `colSums()`.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: `n.actors$sum <- rowSums(n.actors[,-1])`. The `[,-1]` subsets the data so that we have all except the first column, then `rowSums` does what its name suggests. If you have other columns to be excluded, or would prefer to explicitly include specific columns, one might also do `rowSums(subset(n.actors, select = Actor:Writer))` for a range of columns. (The `select=` does what one might want. For instance, `subset(n.actors, select = c(Actor:Composer, Producer:Writer)` selects two ranges of columns. I know that's not what you want here, but I thought it might be useful as you learn R.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. For some reason I wasn't expecting any replies, so it's much appreciated! I took notice and edited my post. Actually was looking for guidelines before posting, but didn't come across this one. Sorry, won't do it again.

Comment: r2evans - thank you, but unfortunately I get an error. "argument "subset" is missing, with no default". Edit: denisafonin - thank you as well, but I'm not sure how to implement it, I don't get anything. Sorry guys, it's my first week and first assignment. I feel really dumb right now, hopefully things get better. I'll go back reading and sort it out. Nonetheless, thanks for your time! Much appreciated everyone. Gilbert

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way of doing this:

```
df$new_col <- df$col1 + df$col2 + ... + df$colN
```